# why doesn't this code switch on the LED on the arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

i was tying to control the brightness of my Arduino using a potentiometer so i made the code below but when i ran it for some reason nothing worked. i tried my setup with another script to test my connections and they were all fine.i noticed that when i set ledVal=potVal/4 it seems to work
can anyone please explain why this works and the code below doesnt thank you

```cpp
int pot = 2;
int ledPin = 11;
int ledVal;
int potVal;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  potVal = analogRead(pot);
  ledVal = (potVal/1024)*255;
  analogWrite(ledPin, ledVal);
  delay(250);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are doing integer math.  Let's look at what happens when you evaluate this:

```
ledVal=(potVal/1024)*255;
```

Since both potVal and 1024 are int then the math will be done with int.  The largest potVal could possibly be is 1023.  1023 /1024 is 0.  Remember these are int so there are no decimals.  Now we take 0 * 255 which is obviously still 0.

If you want to use this particular calculation you would need to use floating point math.  Now this is much slower and takes a lot more code space but this is what it would look like:

```
ledVal=(potVal/1024.0)*255;
```

Now since we use 1024.0 (note we've added the decimal point so it is a float) we get to use float math and 1023/1024 = 0.999-something instead of 0.  When we multiply that times 255 we get the number you expected.

You have already found the better way to do this.  Since analogWrite takes an int it doesn't add anything to have a decimal part to what you give there.  So simply dividing by 4 and throwing away the decimal gets the exact same effect in much less code space.

Comment: In reality, an even better way would be to use ledVal=potVal >> 2; as bitshifts are WAY faster than divide, but the compiler will probably already optimize a divide by 4 to a bitshift anyway so it is probably a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you could try and use the `map` function:

```c
int pot = 2;
int ledPin = 11;
int ledVal = 0;
int potVal = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
}
    
void loop() {
    potVal = analogRead(pot);
    ledVal = map(potVal, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    analogWrite(ledPin, ledVal);
    delay(250);
}
```

More information can be found here:
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/